# How do I check in a condition in Uniface whether a string variable is null?

Tags: uniface

I want to check in Uniface in a condition whether a string variable is null.

How do I do this in Uniface?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

```
variables
    string  my_variable 
endvariables

if( my_variable = "")
      ;is executed if my_variable is null
endif
```